# $G=U\cap F$, where $U\subseteq X$ is closed, iff $G\subseteq F$ closed in $X$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $F\subseteq X$ closed.

I want to proof that $G\subseteq F$ closed in $F$ iff $G\subseteq F$ closed in $X$.

I have a theorem that gives me a jump start. It says, that $G\subseteq F$ closed in $F$ iff $G=U\cap F$, where $U\subseteq X$ is closed in $X$.

So what I need to show is that $G=U\cap F$, where $U\subseteq X$ is closed, iff $G\subseteq F$ closed in $X$.

Assume that $G=U\cap F$, where $U\subseteq X$ is closed in $X$.

Now, both $F,U\subseteq X$ are closed in X. So, their intersection is also closed in $X$. So $G$ is closed in $X$.

Now, assume that $G\subseteq F$ is closed in $X$. Let $G=U$. Now $U\cap F=U$, where $U$ is closed in $X$.

---

Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G \subseteq F$ is closed in $X$, take that as your $U$ as well, so $U = G$. What is $U \cap F$ in this case?